# $language gives unexpected result

Tags: mongodb

My document:

```
{
  name: 'mcrtwrtretca'
}
```

My index:

```
{
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "$**_text",
        "ns" : "mydb.cvs",
        "background" : true,
        "weights" : {
            "$**" : 1
        },
        "default_language" : "english",
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 3
    }
```

Query 1:

```
db.getCollection('cvs').find({$text: {$search: 'mcrtwrtretca', $language: 'english'}})
```

Returns 1 item.

Query 2:

```
db.getCollection('cvs').find({$text: {$search: 'mcrtwrtretca', $language: 'swedish'}})
```

Returns 0 items.

Query 3

```
db.getCollection('cvs').find({$text: {$search: 'mcrtwrtretca', $language: 'dutch'}})
```

Returns 1 item.

If I remove the 'a' at the end all three returns results.

I don't get it. Should't it always get a hit if there is an exact match regardless of the `$language`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify language you tell mongo to use language-specific stop-words and suffix stemming. If you use different languages to index document and to query document, the results may be unexpected because of different rules in different languages. In your particular case, it must be because `a` is a common word-building suffix in Swedish, but not in English.

If you need to support multiple languages, you need to [specify language in the document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/) itself.

If you are interesting in exact match only, use language 'none' in both index and queries.

Read more about how text search works in mongo here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/

Comment: There isn't unless language in the query matches language in the document. When both are the same though, the same suffix stemming and stop words rules apply to both document and query, which results with more accurate text search. E.g. if you change the document to `{"name" : "mcrtwrtretca", "language" : "swedish"}`, it will be returned for both search terms `mcrtwrtretc` and `mcrtwrtretca`, when you specify query language as "swedish".